# How to retrieve an xml page found on a page?

Tags: xml, http

I have an HTTP link like this, where the last number in the link denotes a gene id.

http://glioblastoma.alleninstitute.org/ish/gene/show/22

If you click on it, it will lead you to a page where at the bottom it says "This data is also available as XML" with the link for the XML file. I want to download and save the XML file for hundreds of such gene ids. How can I do that without clicking on each page and saving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link takes you to [deep breath] ...

```
http://glioblastoma.alleninstitute.org/api/v2/data/SectionDataSet/query.xml?order=specimen_types.name$asc&numRows=all&criteria=rma::criteria,products\[id$eq17\],genes\[id$eq22\],rma::include,genes,specimen(donor(age),specimen_types),section_images\[image_type$eqPrimary\],rma::options\[only$eq%27genes.id,id,specimens.id,specimens.external_specimen_name,specimen_types.name,donors.molecular_subtype,ages.name,sub_images.path,sub_images.x,sub_images.y,sub_images.width,sub_images.height,sub_images.tier_count,failed%27\]
```

... which is part of [this API](http://help.brain-map.org/display/glioblastoma/API). Note the number **22** appears in there and can be replaced with any other gene id.

If you prefer the common name then ...

```
http://glioblastoma.alleninstitute.org/api/v2/data/SectionDataSet/query.xml?order=specimen_types.name$asc&numRows=all&criteria=rma::criteria,products\[id$eq17\],genes\[acronym$eqABL1\],rma::include,genes,specimen(donor(age),specimen_types),section_images\[image_type$eqPrimary\],rma::options\[only$eq%27genes.id,id,specimens.id,specimens.external_specimen_name,specimen_types.name,donors.molecular_subtype,ages.name,sub_images.path,sub_images.x,sub_images.y,sub_images.width,sub_images.height,sub_images.tier_count,failed%27\]
```

... allows you to search for **ABL1** or **MECOM**

To script this, I suggest putting all your gene acronymns into a file then doing this:

```sh
cat geneAcronyms | xargs -n 1 -I{} curl -o {}.xml 'http://glioblastoma.alleninstitute.org/api/v2/data/SectionDataSet/query.xml?order=specimen_types.name$asc&numRows=all&criteria=rma::criteria,products\[id$eq17\],genes\[acronym$eq{}\],rma::include,genes,specimen(donor(age),specimen_types),section_images\[image_type$eqPrimary\],rma::options\[only$eq%27genes.id,id,specimens.id,specimens.external_specimen_name,specimen_types.name,donors.molecular_subtype,ages.name,sub_images.path,sub_images.x,sub_images.y,sub_images.width,sub_images.height,sub_images.tier_count,failed%27\]'
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much. I had a tough time converting it into bash since there are '$' symbols, but I managed to do it -